# Second Database Not configured Error in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, database, laravel

Friends, I am trying to develop a package in Laravel 5.3 release by using two databases within the host. The first, default, db connects to users table for all authentication and the second is specific to client. I may have many clients and each client will have his own set of tables within the host. It can be done in a single db but i am trying to do this for a specific reason.

The problem is i am getting an error that Dabatabase [18547383] not configured but it is configured and present in the system. The top of backtrace is reproduced below.

`in DatabaseManager.php line 242`
`at DatabaseManager->getConfig('18547383') in DatabaseManager.php line 160`
`at DatabaseManager->makeConnection('18547383') in DatabaseManager.php line 68`
`at DatabaseManager->connection('18547383') in Model.php line 3351`
`at Model::resolveConnection('18547383') in Model.php line 3317`

Upon probing a bit in the DatabaseManager.php, at line 240, I have tried to introduce an error to see the data present in the config array.

Strangely, all three named (defined in config) connections viz. mysql, mysql2 and pgsql have the same array values. In fact the pgsql configurations have not been populated in the config file yet they have the same values as that of the default. Hence, it is not finding the second db in the array and hence the error.

The question is, is it a bug in L5.3 ? how can I correctly populate the database connections so that it recognizes the second database.

Comment: Check this link: http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

Comment: In fact I had gone through this as well as many links. All the possible approaches described in the above link to connect have not given me the result. I followed this link to connect to second db

Comment: Friends, finally solved it. The solution is to remove the block of db entries in the .env file present in the root. You can see this at the end of this (http://tutsnare.com/connect-multiple-databases-in-laravel/)